# connect infiniband with intel mpi or other mpi(like openMPI)

Tags: windows, parallel-processing, openmpi, infiniband, intel-mpi

I'm new about how to build a infiniband network, and i have not find some useful url about how to do it in windows OS.
I wanna to do that need to connect 5~8 servers with infiniband network in windows OS, and i choose the intel mpi for IB and wanna to use these servers to do some parallel computing...
Is there a freshman tutorial that can ask me how to connect multi nodes with infiniband network using intel MPI or OpenMPI in windows OS?Or maybe what should I know before starting it.

thanks for help.
Ps: I have tried google search and try to find some videos in Youtube also，but not my expectation.

Comment: Why would not you try Microsoft MPI that is bundled with [Microsoft HPC Pack](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc514029)?

Comment: Sorry reply late, i will find some info about the Microsoft HPC right now.And the Pack support infiniband network?